# How can I prevent my Python exe file to close the window after finishing the task?

Tags: python, cmd, exe

I made an assignment of a weekly savings calculator and after generating the exe file and run it, it will open cmd, prompt for the required inputs and closes immediately after making the calculations and displaying a list. I'd like the program window to stay open while displaying the list so the user can take notes if desired.

```
weeks = []
#Creates a list with each week's amount for the selected number of periods.
def create_list(amount, periods):
    counter = 0
    savings = 0
    while (counter < periods):
        savings += amount
        weeks.append(savings)
        counter += 1
#Formats each item in the list and prints it separately.
def display(lists):
    i = 1
    for entry in lists:
        print ("On period {} you should deposit ${} ".format(str(i), entry))
        i += 1

def main():
    amount = int(input("Enter savings amount you want to start with: "))
    periods = int(input("For how many periods do you want to save?: "))
    print()
    create_list(amount, periods)
    display(weeks)
    total = sum(weeks)
    print ("\nAfter {} periods you will have ${} saved.".format(periods, total))

main()
```

Comment: What about using `input`? Something like `input("Press Enter to continue.")` at the end of `main`

Comment: Python doesn't close the window. Whatever you're using to run the script does it when the script ends.

Comment: Thank you Ismael! that was a simple and effective solution.